# How to avoid getters when using mybatis dynamic sql?

Tags: mybatis

In mybatis we can write an update statement like this:

```
<update id="update" parameterType="com.test.User">
  update USERS
  <set>
    <if test="user.name != null">NAME=#{user.name},</if>
    <if test="user.age != null">AGE=#{user.age}</if>
  </set>
</update>
```

Then it requires `User` class to have getters for `name` and `age` properties, without the update statement, the mapping can work without adding any getters, is there a way to avoid the getters for the update statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you use the latest version 3.5.1 (the [change](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/1258) was made in 3.5.0).

If you cannot upgrade for some reason, it may still work if you 1) remove the `@Param("user")` from the method parameter and 2) reference the fields directly as follows.

```xml
<update id="update">
  update USERS
  <set>
    <if test="name != null">NAME=#{name},</if>
    <if test="age != null">AGE=#{age}</if>
  </set>
</update>
```

The direct property reference works only when the bean (i.e. `User`) is the only parameter to the mapper method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, upgraded to 3.5.1, it worked. For the old version, removing the `@Param("user")` not working. Thanks very much.